# Rundeck instance-scope-node-attribute fro WorkflowNodeStep

Tags: rundeck

Workflow Steps do not get variables from the defined executor.
Why is it not possible to get values from key storage from the instance-scope-node-attributes as the NodeExecutors can?

Apparently the instance-scope-node-attribute is ignored in WorkflowNodeStep.

Comment: Hi! Could you post an example? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: We are developing a script WorkFlowNodeStep plugin for a connection to a cloud service. The connection needs Id, Secret, SubscriptionID and other variables to create a bearer token. Supplying these values in configuration fields in the Workflow step seems redundant as the variables are always the same and have to be repeated for each step created. It would be better to be able to define them once in the Node declaration and have the step pick up the values.
Node Execution plugins use this feature but they exclusive to Execution and File copier plugins.

Comment: Which Rundeck version are you using? Since Rundeck 3.3.7 you can create option plugins that access the Key Storage, take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/pull/6642